# Add padding on view programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, padding

I am developing Android v2.2 app.

I have a `Fragment`. In the `onCreateView(...)` callback of my fragment class, I inflate an layout to the fragment like below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
        
    return view;
}
```

The above inflated layout file is (login.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username" />

    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to set a `paddingTop` to the above `<LinearLayout>` element , and I want to do it in the **Java** code instead of do it in xml.

How to set `paddingTop` to `<LinearLayout>` in my fragment Java class code ??

Comment: You'll need to assign an ID to your LinearLayout so that you could find it with `findViewById`and then call `setPadding` on it.

Comment: @AleksG In general yes, but given that the LinearLayout is the root element of the inflated hierachy that's not neccessary here. `view` is already the LinearLayout, no need to find it again in this case. Given this is a special one though.

Comment: @alextsc: yes, agree.  Nevertheless, I still prefer to assign ID's to anything that I may refer to in the application.

Answer (score 582, accepted):

[`view.setPadding(0,padding,0,0);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

This will set the top padding to `padding`-pixels.

If you want to set it in `dp` instead, you can do a [conversion](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels):

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dpAsPixels = (int) (sizeInDp*scale + 0.5f);
```

Comment: @Leem.fin as Chris says, it's pixels. If you want dp you'll have to do the conversion manually:
`float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`  `int size = (int) (sizeInPx*scale + 0.5f);`

Comment: Where is the 0.5f coming from?

Comment: @Georg That code is taken from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels
The 0.5 is used to get the closest integer when casting (instead of using Math.round())

Comment: I think the variable names should be the other way around: `sizeInDp` is actually the number of pixels you get when converting `sizeInPx` dps.

Answer (score 148):

To answer your second question:

```
view.setPadding(0,padding,0,0);
```

like SpK and Jave suggested, will set the padding in pixels. You can set it in dp by calculating the dp value as follows:

```
int paddingDp = 25;
float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
int paddingPixel = (int)(paddingDp * density);
view.setPadding(0,paddingPixel,0,0);
```

Comment: Off course this will compile and work as expected, but for the sake of clarity you should switch the naming of your int variables. Because you define your padding in DP and calculate what it would be in pixels for this given device.

Comment: You are converting dp to pixel. The variable names are confusing. "paddingPixel" really means dp

Answer (score 115):

If you store the padding in resource files, you can simply call

```
int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.padding);
```

It does the conversion for you.

Answer (score 74):

Using Kotlin and the android-ktx library, you can simply do

```
view.updatePadding(top = 42)
```

[See docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#%28android.view.View%29.updatePadding%28kotlin.Int%2C+kotlin.Int%2C+kotlin.Int%2C+kotlin.Int%29)

Answer (score 20):

You can set padding to your view by pro grammatically throughout below code -

```
view.setPadding(0,1,20,3);
```

And, also there are different type of padding available -

[Padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apadding)

[PaddingBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apaddingBottom)

[PaddingLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apaddingLeft)

[PaddingRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apaddingRight)

[PaddingTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apaddingTop)

These, links will refer Android Developers site. Hope this helps you lot.

Comment: @Leem.fin [Have a look at this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/940096) you'll be able to know the difference.

Answer (score 13):

Using `TypedValue` is a much cleaner way of converting to pixels compared to manually calculating:

```
float paddingDp = 10f;
// Convert to pixels
int paddingPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, paddingDp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
view.setPadding(paddingPx, paddingPx, paddingPx, paddingPx);
```

Essentially, `TypedValue.applyDimension` converts the desired padding into pixels appropriately depending on the current device's display properties.

For more info see: [TypedValue.applyDimension Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)).

**Kotlin; extension function**

```
fun Float.px(m: DisplayMetrics!): Int
    get() = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, this, m).toInt()

...
val pad = 10.0f.px
```

Comment: shouldn't px and dp be reversed?

Comment: I think the gist of what I am doing is correct. However the naming is confusing I think. I will edit it to be more clear. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 10):

Use the below method for setting `padding` dynamically

```
setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

Example:

```
view.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here you can see in which section the padding is applied

```
bidding.subHeader.tvSubHeader.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
```

Someone edited this answer, but I added an image that had been removed before, here it is again

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1:** First, take the padding value as an integer.

`int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.padding);`

**or** `int padding = 16;` [Use any method]

**Step 2:** Then assign the padding value to the layout.

`layout.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);`

> layout.setPadding(padding_left, padding_top, padding_right, padding_bottom);

All side different padding can be assigned. `layout.setPadding(16, 10, 8, 12);`

For **removing padding** (No Padding) set padding values as 0,

`layout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Write Following Code to set padding, it may help you.

```
TextView ApplyPaddingTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
final LayoutParams layoutparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ApplyPaddingTextView.getLayoutParams();

layoutparams.setPadding(50,50,50,50);

ApplyPaddingTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
```

Use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` or `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` according to parent layout of the child view

Comment: setPadding() is not an accessible method from LayoutParams. I'm not sure if it ever was.

Answer (score 2):

```
Context context = MainActivity.this;
TextView tView = new TextView(context);
tView.setPaddingRelative(10,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is **not to write your own funcion.**

Let me explain the motivaion - please lookup the official Android source code.

In `TypedValue.java` we have:

```java
    public static int complexToDimensionPixelSize(int data,
            DisplayMetrics metrics)
    {
        final float value = complexToFloat(data);
        final float f = applyDimension(
                (data>>COMPLEX_UNIT_SHIFT)&COMPLEX_UNIT_MASK,
                value,
                metrics);
        final int res = (int) ((f >= 0) ? (f + 0.5f) : (f - 0.5f));
        if (res != 0) return res;
        if (value == 0) return 0;
        if (value > 0) return 1;
        return -1;
    }
```

and:

```java
    public static float applyDimension(int unit, float value,
                                       DisplayMetrics metrics)
    {
        switch (unit) {
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_PX:
            return value;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP:
            return value * metrics.density;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_SP:
            return value * metrics.scaledDensity;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_PT:
            return value * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/72);
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_IN:
            return value * metrics.xdpi;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_MM:
            return value * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/25.4f);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

As you can see, `DisplayMetrics metrics` can differ, which means it would yield **different values a**cross Android-OS powered devices.

I strongly recommend putting your dp padding in dimen xml file and **use the official Android conversions** to have consistent behaviour with regard to how Android framework works.

Comment: i want to follow this solution but what to do if the padding is coming as a constant from api?

Answer (score 1):

Using Jave's solution.

```
public static int getResourceDimension(Context context, String name, String defType, String defPackage) {
    int sizeInDp = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage);
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        sizeInDp = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int dpAsPixels = (int) (sizeInDp*scale + 0.5f);

    return dpAsPixels;
}
```

Then call when needed.

```
int statusBarHeight = getResourceDimension(getContext(), "status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
statusBarHeight = (int) (statusBarHeight + getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fragment_vertical_padding));
view.setPadding(0, statusBarHeight, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

While padding programmatically, convert to density related values by converting pixel to Dp.

Answer (score 0):

```
    binding.appBarMain.toolbar.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, insets ->
        val statusBarSize: Int =
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                insets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars()).top
            } else {
                insets.systemWindowInsetTop
            }
        binding.appBarMain.appBarLayout.setPadding(0, statusBarSize, 0, 0)
        return@setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener insets
    }
```