# Android - Get button's border width

Tags: android, button, size, width, border

How can I get the border width of a stand Android button programmatically? I simply need to resize the text to fit to the gray are, but I cannot do that without knowing the size of the border. Thanks http://s4.postimg.org/9w7idof4d/screenshot_Border_Width.png

Comment: Did you try to use padding? Somethink like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685658/add-padding-on-view-programmatically)

Comment: I have the padding set to 0. Also, I would like to completely avoid XML because I don't even know where to begin in making XML work dynamically.

Comment: try to change the values in code using setPadding method. [setPadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: I already did that.
cmdView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
That does not work.

Comment: The text will fit correctly if I can set it to the correct size. I just need to find the width of the actual button not including its border, and pass it to my SetTextSize function.

Comment: The image is just a drawable shape. Try my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the button's border size in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374977/how-to-get-the-buttons-border-size-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the width and height of the button's border:

```
final Button button = new Button(this);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
layout.addView(button, params);
button.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         button.buildDrawingCache();
         Bitmap viewCopy = button.getDrawingCache();

         boolean stillBorder = true;
         PaddingLeft = 0;
         PaddingTop = 0;
         while (stillBorder)
         {
             int color = viewCopy.getPixel(PaddingLeft, button.getHeight() / 2);
             if (color != Color.TRANSPARENT)
                 stillBorder = false;
             else
             PaddingLeft++;
         }              
         stillBorder = true;
         while (stillBorder)
         {
             int color = viewCopy.getPixel(button.getWidth() / 2, PaddingTop);
             if (color != Color.TRANSPARENT)
                 stillBorder = false;
             else
                 PaddingTop++;
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ShapeDrawable bgShape = (ShapeDrawable )btnbck.getBackground();

```
    Rect padding = null;
    bgShape.getPadding(padding );
```

The image of button is just a drawable object. So you have to get the value of it. Anyway it can do with the shape anything you want.

Comment: This won't work. This line of code:
    ShapeDrawable bgShape = (ShapeDrawable) cmdView.getBackground();
prevents my program from running

Comment: I changed Rect padding = null; to Rect padding = new Rect(); and ShapeDrawable to Drawable and my program no longer crashes, however the padding returned is completely the wrong value. I read somewhere that the standard buttons are use NinePatchDrawable images. I think thats the problem. I've found no way to get the background as a NinePatchDrawable

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a solution. The default padding for spinners happens to be the same as the border of a button.

```
int paddingLeft = mySpinner.getPaddingLeft();
```

Hopefully it will be the same on all devices.

Edit: It is not the same on all devices. I still don't have a working solution