# How to get the button's border size in Android

Tags: java, android, button, size, border

How can I get the border width of a stand Android button programmatically? I simply need to resize the text to fit to the gray area and need to position other objects inline with the buttons, but I cannot do that without knowing the size of the border. I need this to work in all API's 7+. The red arrows in the image below show what I am trying to get:

[image: Border Width]

Here is the code I use for creating my button:

```
cmdView = new Button(this);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthLblViewVerbs , (int) fieldHeight);
params.leftMargin = (int) (screenWidth - params.width);
params.topMargin = (int) yPos;
cmdView.setSingleLine();
cmdView.setText("View");
cmdView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
cmdView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, SetTextSize(cmdView.getText().toString(), params.width, params.height));
layout.addView(cmdView, params);
```

NB. I've had to ask this question again because someone downvoted my question last time and I am desperate for a solution. I have made absolutely no progress with my program in weeks because I have been stuck with this and another problem. If there is something unclear about my question, please let me know and I will edit it. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried changing the padding?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it does not work

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using for creating the button?

Comment: I have moved the code for generating my button from a comment, to part of the question

Comment: I suppose you could get the number of pixels of padding for the `mdpi` version (where `1px == 1dp`) and use that as a base value for figuring out the padding on other densities. Assuming the actual padding on the background increases by the same factor as the density, that should give you the right value.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the highlight part from the drawables that compose the state of the `Button`. Check this out https://gist.github.com/luksprog/5940136 . Also, posting a question and getting a downvote(or needing badly a response) isn't a reason to repost the question, always **improve** the first question with more details(and/or bounties).

Comment: @Luksprog thanks for your help. The link you provided helped me figure out a solution. Can you please copy and paste my answer so I can award you with the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial code recommendation from the comments can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/luksprog/5940136). The implementation done by Dan Bray is:

```
final Button button = new Button(this);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
layout.addView(button, params);
button.post(new Runnable()
{
@Override
public void run()
{
    button.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap viewCopy = button.getDrawingCache();

    boolean stillBorder = true;
    PaddingLeft = 0;
    PaddingTop = 0;
    while (stillBorder)
    {
        int color = viewCopy.getPixel(PaddingLeft, button.getHeight() / 2);
        if (color != Color.TRANSPARENT)
            stillBorder = false;
        else
            PaddingLeft++;
    }              
    stillBorder = true;
    while (stillBorder)
    {
        int color = viewCopy.getPixel(button.getWidth() / 2, PaddingTop);
        if (color != Color.TRANSPARENT)
            stillBorder = false;
        else
            PaddingTop++;
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear on the question - you want the margins of the underlying view and then the set the size of the button to match ? Then Have you tried

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
```

margins are accessible via

```
lp.leftMargin;
lp.rightMargin;
lp.topMargin;
lp.bottomMargin;
```

Details here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Comment: I've added these 4 lines of code:
`View view = (View) cmdView;
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
paddingLeft = lp.leftMargin;
paddingTop = lp.topMargin;`
Unfortunately, it prevents my program from starting. I am basically trying to get the length of the red arrows on the image I posted

Answer (score 1):

This gets the width and height of the button's border:

```
final Button button = new Button(this);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
layout.addView(button, params);
button.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        button.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap viewCopy = button.getDrawingCache();

        boolean stillBorder = true;
        PaddingLeft = 0;
        PaddingTop = 0;
        while (stillBorder)
        {
            int color = viewCopy.getPixel(PaddingLeft, button.getHeight() / 2);
            if (color != Color.TRANSPARENT)
                stillBorder = false;
            else
                PaddingLeft++;
        }              
        stillBorder = true;
        while (stillBorder)
        {
            int color = viewCopy.getPixel(button.getWidth() / 2, PaddingTop);
            if (color != Color.TRANSPARENT)
                stillBorder = false;
            else
                PaddingTop++;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a nine patch background image, there is a much easier way.

In the nine patch image, you can define a padding box. This padding box will automatically be applied to the contents you set. No need to recalculate the paddings manually in that case.

Note that you should not set a padding on views using a nine patch as a background as the padding from the nine patch will be ignored.