# Overlapping row in listview

Tags: android, listview, view, android-canvas

How to create this below view.

1)using listview or

2)inflating custom view in scrollview.
This is not only problem.

If list view then how to overlap the rows.

**Each row have different color and that will come from api webservice**.[image]

In listview, at each row i have problem with red part which i have marked in second image.
even each row background is different and that same color will appear in below  row.

How to do texture effect in listview?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue breaks to many things:

1. How to draw overlapping views?
   I would try setting negative values for vertical paddings, but it's a wild guess. Also, you can just divide the graphics and draw views as rectangles containing view N and some parts of the N+1th view.
2. What about non-rectangular hit area?
   You can manually detect clicks using color picking, shapes, or just simplify the view's clickable area to a rectangle.
3. What about visibility detection?
   ListView shows only views, which are visible. I'm not sure, but most likely it won't work with negative paddings or similar hacks.

Personally I would write a custom view with ListView-like adapter and dynamic row loading.

Comment: if i will create list view then problem with overlapping concept in custom list view.

Comment: in 1st option. how to set vertical padding in minues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685658/add-padding-on-view-programmatically you can set top and bottom paddings

Comment: still its not working . i try with bottom margin and with bottom padding in negative but its not working.

Comment: Just like I wrote on the beginning, it's a wild guess. Probably you will need to write your own list with overlapping views. This approach is the most time-consuming, but it gives you the most control over the stuff you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I have try a many ways, and the **best** and **fastest** is simple set negative divider to listview like so:

```
android:dividerHeight="-100dp"
```