# How to add space between textviews which is in TableRow?

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I Displayed my program's output via `TableRow` in  `TableLayout` using array of `Textview`.Actually the output is of 2d array.
I displayed every element of 2d array without any problems.
But what the problem is I cant have space between `TextViews(Columns)`.
Below is the image which explains this clearly.I want to do this programmatically

[image]

Please help me to solve this

Comment: You can use 'padding' or 'margin' in your xml layouts

Comment: @Merlevede Sorry I edited.I want to do this only by programmatically

Comment: Anybody please help to solve this...

Answer (score 1):

Remember that almost any property that can be set on your XML layout, can also be set programmatically!

The way to do it is:

```
view.setPadding(0,padding,0,0);
```

This will set the top padding to padding-pixels. If you want to set it in dp instead, you can do a conversion:

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dpAsPixels = (int) (sizeInDp*scale + 0.5f);
```

I go this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685658/add-padding-on-view-programmatically) .

Comment: Sir I am new to android.If you dont mind can you explain me where and how to use this??

Comment: We're here to assist you and pointing you in the right direction, but I'm afraid you have to do some research on your own too.

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding programmatically on the textview by using this method:

```
txt.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

set integer value for left,top,right,bottom according to your condition.Hope it will help...