# How to set Top padding for image of a dynamic button with image and text

Tags: android, android-button

I have looked at various questions on this but, couldn't get them work.

I have a button, with a background, image on top and text at the bottom. The button is dynamic and hence NO XML is available.

Code for the dynamic button:

```
            final Button image = new Button(this);
            image.setTag(i);
            image.setText(buttonsList[i].toUpperCase());
            image.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            image.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));

            if (i == Const.MainIndex.FESTIVAL_OUTLOOK_INDEX) {

                try {
                    XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(
                            R.color.text_color_green);
                    ColorStateList colors = ColorStateList.createFromXml(
                            getResources(), parser);
                    image.setTextColor(colors);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                //setting this value to -ve decreases the 
                            //gap between the image and text
                image.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-100);
                image.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        null,
                        getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.sidemenu_image_festout), null, null);




                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_green);
            }
```

Here is how the image looks now..

[image]

I want to set padding on TOP of the image. So that the image doesn't look to close to the border of the button. How can I achieve this?

I have tried setting `image.setPadding(0,10,0,0)` but no effect.

Comment: try margin for the image

Comment: Maybe you should make a conversion to dp, this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685658

Comment: @Fllo, I gave it a try. No effect.

Comment: did you figure it out? I think it cannot be done by creating a button. Create a dynamic layout either Linear or Relative and handle the clicks like a button

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

use this

Comment: Its a dynamic button, how do I get the LayoutParams?