# android correct padding between views programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview, android-layoutparams

I programmatically created four **Textviews** and added it in my `Linearlayout`.my linearlayout has **216dp width** and `TextView` which I created pro-grammatically has 48 dp width and height.
I want to add padding between `TextView`. I wrote some code but I received this result

[image: as you can see padding is not correct,because in right side is incorrect]

this is a my code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mDigits; i++) {
        DigitView digitView = new DigitView(getContext());

        digitView.setWidth(valueInPixels);//48dp
        digitView.setHeight(valueInPixels);//48dp
        digitView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        digitView.setTextSize(mDigitTextSize);
        digitView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            digitView.setElevation(mDigitElevation);
        }

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (i > 0) {
            lp.leftMargin = 10;//problem is this line
        }
        childView.addView(digitView, lp);//childview 216dp
    }
```

how i can to create correct padding between views `programmatically`?
if anyone has solution please help me
thanks.

Comment: Add margin to your dynamic text fields and remove this part:LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (i > 0) {
            lp.leftMargin = 10;//problem is this line
        }

Comment: @TdSoft  i don't know how to do this.can you show me source or update my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add padding on view programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685658/add-padding-on-view-programmatically)

Comment: @Nanoc thanks.but i know to to add padding but as i said my container has 216 dp width and in my views has 48dp width and simple i want same padding between my views.please see my picture

Comment: @donoachua pls check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add appropriate android:paddingLeft to your childview I added as below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/childView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Then edit you code as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            DigitView digitView = new DigitView(this);

            digitView.setWidth(valueInPixels);//48dp
            digitView.setHeight(valueInPixels);//48dp
            digitView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            digitView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            digitView.setTextSize(mDigitTextSize);
            digitView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                digitView.setElevation(mDigitElevation);
            }

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            lp.rightMargin = 10;//problem is this line

            childView.addView(digitView, lp);//childview 216dp
        }
```

Comment: thank youy but 5dp and rightMargin meybe is not correct solution because different screen size meybe would be problem

Comment: Use values/dimen.xml to define padding sizes for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

[Add padding on view programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685658/add-padding-on-view-programmatically)

Here you have the solution to create a padding in java code.

Comment: thanks.but i  know to to add padding but as i said my container has 216 dp width and in my views has 48dp width and simple i want same padding between my views.please see my picture

Comment: Use values/dimen.xml to define parking sizes for different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> public void setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

```
view.setPadding(0,padding,0,0);
```

Comment: thanks.but i know to to add padding but as i said my container has 216 dp width and in my views has 48dp width and simple i want same padding between my views.please see my picture @Parth Bhayani

Comment: for that, you need to give the weight for each of your view and add that view to your activity, that works fine.