# EditText Padding not Working as Expected in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

I have test on `MarshMallow` device. When I write xml for `EditText` and set `PaddingBottom` to `Retype EditText`. but it is not Working. But When I set `PaddingLeft` to `New PassWord` `EditText` is working fine.

## Approch : 1

**xml Code :**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/change_password_old_password_edittext"
            android:layout_below="@+id/change_password_mobileNumber_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Old Password"
            android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip"
            android:textColorHint="#40000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize16"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/change_password_new_password_edittext"
            android:layout_below="@+id/change_password_old_password_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="New Password"
            android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip"
            android:textColorHint="#40000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize16"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/change_password_retype_password_edittext"
            android:layout_below="@+id/change_password_new_password_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Retype Password"
            android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:textColorHint="#40000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize16"/>
```

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

## Approch : 2

Then I decide to set `PaddingBottom` programatically. But It is giving weird Output.

**java code :**

inside `OnCreate` method

```
   EditText change_password_retype_password_edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.change_password_retype_password_edittext);
        change_password_retype_password_edittext.setPadding(0,0,0,10);
```

**Output :**

[image]

> **Note :**  I have tested on `Marshmallow` , `LolliPop` and also `Jellybean`. But in all device is not Working.

Comment: It seems no problem with the layout. Post the whole layout code.

Comment: @AkshayBhat did you see the Screen Shot The Problem is Display..

Comment: Yes, but i copied your layout code and tried, it is working fine

Comment: @AkshayBhat post the screenShot..

Comment: Screen shot :  http://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ6cP.png

Comment: @AkshayBhat where is the `BottomPadding`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117158/discussion-between-akshay-bhat-and-ironman).

Comment: you are passing a float value in both those edittext that is not working try to use 20dip instead @Ironman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are not specifying the unit of padding you have set so it is taking `pixel` by default which is smaller then `dp` so the results are not as per your expectations.

Convert the pixels to dp you will get the solution :

```
int paddingPixel = 10;
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int paddingDp = (int)(paddingPixel * density);
change_password_retype_password_edittext.setPadding(0,0,0,paddingDp);
```

For more info visit : [Add padding on view programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685658/add-padding-on-view-programmatically)

Comment: glad to know that happy coding..!! :)

Comment: when I set `paddingLeft` on this code then only it display `PaddingBottom` not `PaddingLeft` too.

Comment: are you setting in first arguement ?? of `setPadding` ? make sure you do not have any xml padding when you are programattically setting the padding other wise they will conflict..!!

Comment: Thanx But I found What I do mistake in my Xml I set `dip` so It is not display as I expected But I when Change `dip` to `dp` is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
android:drawablePadding="8dp"
```

This padding will to put away the drawable from text cursor
Look the example.[image]