# Convert Dp to Px in Kotlin - This cast can never succeed

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I ran into a problem while coding in Kotlin. I copy-pasted a [java code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685690/6818446) that converts DP to Pixels, in order to place it as a parameter for setting padding programatically. I was expecting the IDE to automatically transform it all to Kotlin, however it failed in the process.

The code in *Java* looks like the following:

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dpAsPixels = (int) (sizeInDp*scale + 0.5f);
```

After the translation to *Kotlin*:

```
val scale = resources.displayMetrics.density
val dpAsPixels = (sizeInDp * scale + 0.5f) as Int
```

The cast `as Int` is marked with the error

> "This cast can never succeed"

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error can be solved by removing the cast `as Int` and instead replace it with the method `.toInt()`

```
val scale = resources.displayMetrics.density
val dpAsPixels = (16.0f * scale + 0.5f).toInt()
```

Answer (score 37):

Why not trying it with an Extension Function such as

```
val Int.dp: Int get() = (this / getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

to convert to DP and

```
val Int.px: Int get() = (this * getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

to convert to Pixels?

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That's the most simple way. The other ones are deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

If you have value in dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="textSize">24dp</dimen>
```

Then, you can get value in pixel as Int

```
val value = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textSize)
```

Comment: This one seems a good approach since we can separate dimens depends on screen resolution aswell.

Answer (score 3):

Extensions.kt file

```
val Int.dp: Int
    get() = (toFloat() * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density + 0.5f).toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these extension functions, it doesn't need `context` and for Int values it rounds it up to next integer value.

```
private fun getDip(): Float = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density
fun Float.dp() = this * getDip()
fun Int.dp() = (this * getDip()).roundToInt()
```

and you can use it like this:

```
val width = 48.dp()
val height = 2.5f.dp()
```